# How to solve Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'agent_id' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: laravel, datatable

Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'agent_id' in where clause is ambiguous

I have try but still can't find the error of this datatables

```
public function customerOrderList(Request $request, $agent_id){
    $customer_orders = CustomerOrder::join('agent as a', 'a.agent_id','=','customer_order.agent_id')
    ->select('customer_order.*', 'a.name as agent_name')
    ->where('agent_id', $agent_id)
    ->get();

    $datatables = DataTables::of($customer_orders)
    ->addColumn('actions', function($customer_order){
      $html ='';
      $view = route('customer-order.invoice', $customer_order->doc_id);
      $html .= "<a class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' href='$view'><i class='far fa-fw fa-eye'></i></a>";

      return $html;
    })
    ->rawColumns(['actions']);

    return $datatables->make(true);
  }
```

-show datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that multiple tables in your query have the same `agent_id` column, and your query cannot determine which one to use. You've used `'customer_order.agent_id'` in one clause, but only `'agent_id'` in the another.

When using `->join()`, it's sometimes required to be as specific as possible with your references (depends on your table structure/columns being selected, etc):

```php
$customer_orders = CustomerOrder::join('agent as a', 'a.agent_id','=','customer_order.agent_id')
  ->select('customer_order.*', 'a.name as agent_name')
  ->where('customer_order.agent_id', $agent_id) // Here, add table name before `agent_id`, likely `customer_order`
  ->get();
```